# WAMP, how to redirect if ip is not authorized

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp

i want to make wamp homepage to be accessed from a list of allowed ip, and the one that are not in the list to be redirected into a webfile. like this..

example.com

allowed ips:
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.174
192.168.1.123
200.256.65.1

thoses that are not in the list are going to be redirected to example.com/test (if possible, to be redirected into that directory but just showing in the explorer example.com).

ive been told to use the htaccess 'RewriteMap' but i dont know how that really works, please someone help

**Updated**: When its accessed from a dns, could it get its ip from where is requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP : First of all get the current domain using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and then identify it's authenticated or not ! Simple. Here's Lil Code Snippet !

> 1) Create a PHP array to store all the allowed domain :

```
$domains = array(
    "127.0.0.1",
    "192.168.1.174",
    "192.168.1.123",
    "200.256.65.1"
);
```

> 2) Create another file domain_check.php and add following code :

```
<?php
    $current_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    if(!in_array($current_domain,$domains)) {
        header("Location: http://google.com");
    }
?>
```

include above file at the top of you pages. It's done :)

Comment: should i set "include(iplistfile)" to call the ip ranges?.. because i was thinking as well if dns example.com go to page example, or test.com go to page test, sorry for asking dumb questions, im new

Comment: after making some research about getting the clients ip throught dns, i guess its better to use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] so it can be more specific when getting ip even from a call by a dns

Comment: @nosthertus : yeah :) great (y)